# Why does SVG allow me to use CSS var without closing bracket?

Tags: css, svg, css-variables

Please see this [example on codepen](https://codepen.io/samrae/pen/VwdqbPx)

I am using a CSS var as the fill prop for the SVG, but I've purposefully left off the closing parenthesis. The colour still displays as intended. Why would this be the case?
[image]

NB: When using the var() in the stylesheet, it's not as forgiving (see the example)

```html
    <body>
    <style>
        :root {
            --main-color: #06c;
        }
        /* If you miss the closing parenthesis from var() the styling breaks, which makes sense*/
        h1 {
          color: var(--main-color);
        }
    </style>

    <h1>Here is my coloured heading</h1>

    <!-- the closing parenthesis from var() is missing, but the colour is still applied. That's good for when you make a mistake, but I dont get why -->
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="var(--main-color" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
    </svg>
    </body>
```

Comment: From what I see in your codepen, as HTML is linked to CSS in the background, it just take the value of `main-color`. Talking about bracket, you mean parenthesis ? 
I think this works because there is no code after. Maybe with following svg tags, it would cause bugs

Comment: Yes by bracket I mean parenthesis. Edited the question to change that. Thanks

Comment: The parser corrects your mistakes when possible. You can also omit quotes around attributes like in : ``<svg height=100 width=100 >``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does also work in CSS but you need to remove the last `}` and have nothing after it:

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #06c;
}
h1 {
  color: var(--main-color
```

```html
<h1>Here is my coloured heading</h1>
```

Sometimes the browser is clever enough "to understand" some broken stuff but you should never rely on such behavior. People use such trick to shorten the code when doing some online challenges for fun or they simply do it by mistake.